# Reading secrets with consul-template from vault

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, consul-template

I have vault running in a pod.
I can read secrets using vault read.

```
$ vault read test
Key                 Value
---                 -----
refresh_interval    768h
value               world

$ vault kv get test
==== Data ====
Key      Value
---      -----
value    world
```

I can use both versions of the Api to see the secrets in vault

When i list vault secret engines i clearly see them:

```
$ vault secrets list
Path                   Type         Description
----                   ----         -----------
secret/                kv           key/value secret storage
test/                  kv           n/a
```

In my Consul-template template i have the following

```
[default]
{{ with secret "test"}}
{{ if .Data.value }}
consul_template_value = {{ .Data.value }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

My consul-template is a sidecar pod reading the file above and returning the current error :

```
watcher reported error: vault.read(test): no secret exists at test
[ERR] (cli) vault.read(test): no secret exists at test
```

I turned on the trace on consul-template sidecar

```
[TRACE] (view) vault.read(test) starting fetch
[TRACE] vault.read(test2): GET /v1/test?stale=true&wait=1m0s
[WARN] (view) vault.read(test): no secret exists at test (retry attempt 1 after "250ms")
```

I checked Vault API with a curl

```
curl -k -H "X-Vault-Token: TOKEN" -X GET https://X.X.X.X/v1/test?stale=true
```

I get the response

```
{
"request_id":"aa947343-723a-45fc-cdee-7394c3074a4c",
"lease_id":"",
"renewable":false,
"lease_duration":2764800,
"data":{
    "value":"word"
    },
"wrap_info":null,
"warnings":null,
"auth":null
}
```

I found a similar issue on github https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/issues/341

Any ideas would be helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved i was missing some configuration aspects of CT

Comment: Some more elaboration beyond this would help others who encounter a similar problem.

Comment: My problem was mainly TLS/SSL, CT was requesting/reading secrets from vault and returning '<' the error was not verbose enough to be detected even when turning the logs to debug or trace

Comment: Otherwise, you can check vault policies because the default one doesn't give you the right to read if you create an engine